# Django - redirect to the previous page

Tags: django, backend

I am creating a function of adding friend to a user's friend list. After a user click the button, the friendship will be created and the page should be redirected to where the user was. For instance, I want to add another user in the first page in the forum, I should stay in the same page after I click the "add friend" button.

This is how I design it:
When I redirect to any page of the forum, I pass the path of the current page as a variable in the page:

```
def to_post_page(request, post_id, page_nr):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=post_id)
    form = CommentForm()
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post)
    return render(request, 'post/post.html', {
        'post': post,
        'form': form,
        'comments': comments,
        'page_nr': int(page_nr),
        'user': request.user,
        'path': request.path,
    })
```

And in the template:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="Add Friend" onclick="location.href='{% url 'user:add_friend' to_friend_id=post.poster.id path=path %}';">

@login_required(login_url='user:login')
def friend_add(request, to_friend_id, path):
    friend = get_object_or_404(User, id=to_friend_id)
    if friend == request.user:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path)

    friendship = FriendShip(
        from_friend=request.user,
        to_friend=friend
    )

    try:
        friendship.save()
    except IntegrityError:
        return path
    finally:
        return path
```

My url looks like this:

```
url(r'^add_friend/(?P<to_friend_id>[0-9]+/)/(?P<path>[\w\-]+)/$', views.friend_add, name="add_friend"),
```

It raises an exception:

> Reverse for 'add_friend' with keyword arguments '{'to_friend_id': 1, 'path': '/forum/1/0/post'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['users/add_friend/(?P[0-9]+/)/(?P[\w\-]+)$']

Can any body explain me why the exception is raised and what is the solution? Isn't \w designed for string parameter?

And I think my way to redirect to the previous page is not very smart. Does any one have a better way?

Really thanks a lot!

The question is not duplicated to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35796195/how-to-redirect-to-previous-page-in-django-after-post-request) because he is using a form but I am not. I have no way to get a POST

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect to previous page in Django after POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35796195/how-to-redirect-to-previous-page-in-django-after-post-request)

Comment: the answer is returning this ==> `HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/'))`

Comment: @mohammedqudah Can you answer it again? I will accept your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Drop `/` from `to_friend` regex as it gonna contain it in the end.

Add `/` to `path` regex part as it's not included in `\w` (alphanumeric: `[0-9a-zA-Z_]`).

This should work:

```
url(r'^add_friend/(?P<to_friend_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<path>[\w\-/]+)/$', views.friend_add, name="add_friend"),
```

Also in your `friend_add` you cannot just return `path` in the end. Enclose it in `HttpResponseRedirect`.

Comment: no, the answer is returning this ==> `HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/'))`

Comment: @mohammedqudah so you have disliked regardless of the fact that I answered on his question about regex problems? nice

Comment: actually I tried your solution, it is not working. but still appreciate your help!

Comment: Seems the value of path is not read after passing to the target page. But your re looks good to me, could be some other problem