# Django Form: Redirect to the page which sent the post request

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I have 2 pages which allow to send user a private message.

On both of these pages I have a form which is processed by the same view e.g.

```
def send_message(request, pk)
    # send this user a message
    return redirect_to_page_which_sent_POST_request
```

So my goal is to use the same method to precess forms on both pages, and redirect back to the page.

[I know I can do this by adding `next` parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35796195/how-to-redirect-to-previous-page-in-django-after-post-request/35796559) to the form but are there any simpler ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem once and I solved it via the URL. Say you have two pages foo and bar, I added the following to the url.

```
/(?P<source>(foo|bar))/
```

Then on on page foo / bar add source='foo' / 'bar' to the POST url. You can then use

```
if source == 'foo':
    return redirect(reverse('foo'))
else:
    return redirect(reverse('bar'))
```

in your view.