# Redirect user to previous page after submitting form in Django

Tags: django, redirect, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to redirect the user to the previous page once a form is submitted.

1. User starts on Venue_id page (http..../show_venue/23/) and clicks on product id
2. User is directed to Product_id page (http..../show_product.../1/) and find a form
3. User completes form and submit on Product_id page
4. user redirect to Venue_id page upon form submission (from http..../show_venue/23/)

http..../show_venue/23/ **->** http..../show_product.../1/ **->** http..../show_venue/23/

I found a good source of inspiration on the forum, particularly on this page ([How to redirect to previous page in Django after POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35796195/how-to-redirect-to-previous-page-in-django-after-post-request))

(I also found some posts using the history of the browser. But decided to stick to this method, as it seems using browser history doesn't always work)

I used `next` as suggested in the code in the above post. But there is something I don't understand which is probably why I get this wrong.

Here is the different codes in views I tried for `next`:

1. `next = request.POST.get('next','/')` => this sends me to '/', which
   is not what i want. However it seemed to work for the person who
   posted the original question even though they were trying to NOT be redirect to '/';
2. `next = request.POST.get('next','')` => sends me to my product_id page url, but the page is empty
3. next = request.POST.get('next') => this one was suggested in other posts, but I get `Field 'id' expected a number but got 'None'`.

I might be completely wrong, but I feel the key is probably there. How to do refer to "`show_venue/<venue_id>`" into "`next = request.POST.get('next','show_venue/<venue_id>')`"?

In terms of code

**Views**

```
def show_product_from_venue(request, product_id):
    product = Product.objects.get(pk=product_id)
    form = ReviewForm()
    venue_form = VenueForm()
    submitted = False
    next = request.POST.get('next')
    if request.method == "POST" and 'btnvenue_form' in request.POST:
        venue_form = VenueForm(request.POST)
        if venue_form.is_valid():
            venue_form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(next)
        else:
            venue_form = VenueForm
            if 'submitted' in request.GET:
                submitted = True
    else:
        print(form.errors)
    return render(request,"main/show_product_from_venue.html", {'form':form, 'submitted':submitted, 'product':product, 'venue_form':venue_form, 'data':data})
```

**Venue_id (template)**

```
<a href="{% url 'show-product-from-venue' product.id %}?next={{ request.path|urlencode }} method="POST">
```

**Product_id(template with form)**

```
<form action="{% url 'show-product-from-venue' product.id%}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form}}
    <input type="submit" name="btnreview_form" name="next" value="{{ request.GET.next }}" class="btn btn-primary custom-btn">
</form>
```

**urls**

```
#VENUE PAGE
path('show_venue/<venue_id>', views.show_venue,name="show-venue"),

#PRODUCT
path('show_product_from_venue/<product_id>', views.show_product_from_venue,name="show-product-from-venue"),
```

Comment: Also share urls.py.

Comment: All done, just uploaded urls.py

Comment: For example if a form comes from `http..../show_venue/23/` so after saving of form you want it to again go to same route with id=23 also, basically the same url, is that what you want?

Comment: Yes correct. Sorry, I should have made that clearer in my question.

Comment: Sorry I misread your post, this is not what I am after. I am going to update my original post to make it clearer: user starts from http..../show_venue/23/, and will land on http..../show_product.../1/. The form is on http..../show_product.../1/. Once submitted, I want the user to be redirected to  http..../show_venue/23/.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go previous pages then just add the root where exactly you want to go:

In views:

**EX:**

```
return HttpResponseRedirect("/users/")
```

Comment: I considered that, but how would you redirect to an id specific url? ('show_venue/<venue_id>'). Obvioulsy the url would be different for each venue id, so I did not thing I could hard code the redirect hence the use of 'next'.