# How can I redirect this to a slug url in django?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

So I have one detail view and one function in my views.py. So i have included the form in detail view template list_detail.html. and upon posting the form successfully. It redirects to all page(homepage basically). Now I want it to redirect to detailview page which is like this. and for that I need to pass the slug value of that List models specific object. But can build the logic here. I am new to django.

```
path('list/<slug:slug>/', TheirDetailView.as_view(),name='list_detail'),
path('all',views.all, name='all'),
path('create_comment',views.create_comment, name='create_comment'),
```

```
class TheirDetailView(DetailView):
    model = List
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        modell = Review.objects.all()
        context["modam"] = modell
        return context
```

```
def create_comment(request):
    context = {}
    form = ReviewForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('app:all')
    else:
        context['form'] = form
        return render(request, "app/create_comment.html", context)
```

Comment: you mean you edited x person's profile and after saving you want to open its updated detailed profile instead homepage right?

Comment: Actually detailview is a blog post page. and create_comment is comment function. so I  included the comment form in detail page. So say a user comment on a post the upon posting I want it to redirect to that same detailview page that I had posted the comment from. Currently I have set the redirect to "all" page. So it takes to the homepage. Sorry if im bad at explaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def create_comment(request):
    # context = {}
    form = ReviewForm(request.POST or None)
    id_List = request.POST["List"]
    slug = List.objects.filter(id=int(id_List)).values("slug").first()
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect("app:list_detail", slug=slug["slug"])
```

Comment: hey here args=(post id,)) is what? I mean there is no post in here. and the comma looks wrong here.

Comment: you're commenting on specific post right? so to save comment ofc you'll have post id in form. pass that id in args

Comment: id is not working. My detailview path takes slug. so i tried this `redirect_url = reverse("app:list_detail", args=(slug,))` it says slug is not defined

Comment: This is my url for list_detail `path('list/<slug:slug>/', TheirDetailView.as_view(),name='list_detail'),`

Comment: `return reverse("list_detail", kwargs={"slug": 'slug_value'})`

Comment: Its going to this link without taking the slugvalue :( `http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/list/slug_value/`

Comment: is it on git? if yes then pls share

Comment: sure man. [Link}(https://github.com/ayat1041/theirlist-website.git)

Comment: ok will update you asap

Comment: when does it get called. `create_comment` i cant find from ui. what is the flow

Comment: @AyatRahman Updated ans. Please check

Comment: Sorry for the delay. In my list_detail. html at line 82 i did this = `{% include 'app/create_comment.html' %}` . and you can see in create_comment.html I have the form action = "create_comment". So from list_detail page im posting a comment to create_comment link. and in create_comment view( line 257 ) if form is valid its gonna take us to all url(which means homepage). But thats what I wanna change. I had passed a context form of ReviewForm in my TheirDetailView (line 115). but realized its not doing anything so I removed it.

Comment: after commenting it will redirect to the same page. updated the answer yesterday. have you checked?

Comment: Hey man! Extremely sorry I didnt notice that. Just tried. Its perfect! Thats exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Hey did some google and found this in stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35796195/how-to-redirect-to-previous-page-in-django-after-post-request) added this line replacing my redirect under my create_comment function if form.is_valid statement

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/'))
```

So my function looks like this

```
def create_comment(request):
    context = {}
    form = ReviewForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/'))
    else:
        context['form'] = form
        return render(request, "app/create_comment.html", context)
```

Weirdly enough its said in the post that it wont work in incognito/private mode but just checked and it does. But even in some articles its discouraged to use this referrer so still looking for a better solution to this. Thanks everyone.